# ADO.NET looking for Bulk Insert - row-by-row is slow as Molasses

Tags: .net, sql-server, .net-core, ado.net

With 20K records to insert, this is taking about an hour. Is there a way to do a ADO.NET insert in bulk instead of a loop that goes forever?

```
private async Task InsertReprocessTsk(List<ReprocessTskChngs> reprocessTskChngs)
{
    using (SqlConnection conn = new SqlConnection(_connectionString))
    {
        await conn.OpenAsync();

        string insertSql = @"insert into REPROCESS_TSK(CRS, TskLOC, PROCESSED, DATE_ENTERED)
                                 Values(@CRS, @TskLOC, @PROCESSED, GETDATE())";

        using SqlTransaction trans = conn.BeginTransaction();
        try
        {

            foreach (ReprocessTskChngs reprocessTskChng in reprocessTskChngs)
            {
                using (SqlCommand cmd = new SqlCommand(insertSql, conn, trans))
                {
                    cmd.Parameters.Add("@CRS", SqlDbType.SmallInt).Value = reprocessTskChng.CRS;
                    cmd.Parameters.Add("@TskLOC", SqlDbType.VarChar).Value = reprocessTskChng.TskLOC;
                    cmd.Parameters.Add("@PROCESSED", SqlDbType.Int).Value = reprocessTskChng.PROCESSED;

                    await cmd.ExecuteNonQueryAsync();

                }
            }

            await trans.CommitAsync();
        }
        catch
        {
            trans.Rollback();
            throw;
        }
    }
}
```

I could find ADO.NET bulk copy operations but nothing specific to insert

Comment: Pass a TableValued Parameter and insert it

Comment: It is not ADO.NET example but  looks like it can work if you are ok with using DataTables https://www.c-sharpcorner.com/blogs/bulk-insert-in-sql-server-from-c-sharp

Comment: You're not doing a bulk insert. You're inserting RBAR (Row-By-Agonizing-Row), that's why it's slow as molasses.

Comment: As a simple example, look at how much slower it is to insert just *50* rows in an RBAR method compared to a single statement: [db<>fiddle](https://dbfiddle.uk/sTpnS3xE) If you have 100's, 1,000's and even 10,000's the time taken is going to be truly awful.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Well, there is a way to insert multiple items at once into a table, but it is exposed to SQL Injection. Instead of creating one insert command for each line you can create bulks of insert statements in a string and execute them all at once. Here is how it would look based on your example:

```
var sqlStatements = new List<string>();
string sqlStatement = string.Empty;
int index = 0;
// process all items
foreach (var reprocessTskChng in reprocessTskChngs)
{
    index++;
    sqlStatement += "insert into REPROCESS_TSK(CRS, TskLOC, PROCESSED, DATE_ENTERED)" +
                    $"Values('{reprocessTskChng.CRS}', '{reprocessTskChng.TskLOC}', '{reprocessTskChng.PROCESSED}', GETDATE());";
    // create a bulk of inserts for every 1000 items
    if (index == 1000)
    {
        sqlStatements.Add(sqlStatement);
        sqlStatement = string.Empty;
        index = 0;
    }
}

// if there are any items left in the bulk insert query
if (index > 0)
{
    sqlStatements.Add(sqlStatement);
    sqlStatement = string.Empty;
}

using (SqlConnection conn = new SqlConnection(connectionString))
{
    await conn.OpenAsync();
    
    using SqlTransaction trans = conn.BeginTransaction();
    try
    {
        // process all bulks of insert statements and execute
        foreach (var statement in sqlStatements)
        {
            using (SqlCommand cmd = new SqlCommand(statement, conn, trans))
            {
                await cmd.ExecuteNonQueryAsync();
            }
        }
        await trans.CommitAsync();
    }
    catch
    {
        trans.Rollback();
        throw;
    }
}
```

For 20k records, in this way, you will execute only 20 queries. The issue is, as mentioned, you won't use SQL command parameters anymore.

Comment: I like it. Looks much improved performance wise. I'll post another comment after I know the results.

Comment: If the DBMS is SQL Server 2008+ and it is feasible to change/create database objects, consider using TVP in this case. Here is a complete example https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/framework/data/adonet/sql/table-valued-parameters.

Answer (score 0):

You can use SQL Server Bulk Copy feature to insert. It is very fast due to minimal logging.

```
    private async Task InsertReprocessTsk(List<ReprocessTskChngs> reprocessTskChngs)
    {
        var table = new DataTable("REPROCESS_TSK");

        table.Columns.Add(new DataColumn("CRS", typeof(short)));
        table.Columns.Add(new DataColumn("TskLOC", typeof(string)));
        table.Columns.Add(new DataColumn("PROCESSED", typeof(int)));


        foreach (ReprocessTskChngs reprocessTskChng in reprocessTskChngs)
        {
            DataRow dataRow = table.NewRow();

            dataRow.SetField("CRS", reprocessTskChng.CRS);
            dataRow.SetField("TskLOC", reprocessTskChng.TskLOC);
            dataRow.SetField("PROCESSED", reprocessTskChng.PROCESSED);

            table.Rows.Add(dataRow);
        }

        using (SqlConnection conn = new SqlConnection(_connectionString))
        {
            await conn.OpenAsync();

            using (var sqlBulkCopy = new SqlBulkCopy(conn))
            {
                sqlBulkCopy.DestinationTableName = table.TableName;

                foreach (var column in table.Columns)
                {
                    sqlBulkCopy.ColumnMappings.Add(column.ToString(), column.ToString());
                }

                await sqlBulkCopy.WriteToServerAsync(_dataTable);
            }
        }
    }
```